# while saving admin cms pages getting 404 not found only for files in magento 2

Tags: magento2, cms, 404, file-permissions

> while saving admin cms pages
> getting 404 not found page

in magento 2

already permission for

```
pub/media 777
var  777
```

how i can solve this

i'm using magento 2.1.11

Edit1:

> I created new cms page when i add text and i saved that  it's working
>
> **if i add any files(image) then i save that i'm getting 404 page error not found**

pub/media permissions

[image]

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: while i saving the page getting 404 error :page not found

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/magento-2-404-page-not-found.html review this

Comment: Try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/79364/60921

Comment: i'm actully getting error for only any images on my page

Comment: Which Magento version are you using?

Comment: magento 2.1.11  @EasyndFaster

Comment: Are you in production mode?

Comment: nope   i'm in developer mode......

Comment: Are you using a multi store?

Comment: Are you eanble this setting admin > stores > configuration > general > general > single-store mode?

Comment: i tried but still getting error....

Answer (score 1):

By default new setup magento never exist same type of issue might be you have add any extension or modify any core file related to block or pages.

If you have not do nothing changes then check var log or server log any issue will display.

Run command for setup upgrade and di compilation and clear cache.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Remove browser cache and just remove generated folder content except .htaccess file.

Comment: i updated question plz check

Comment: please verify with uploading image folder permission.

Comment: where cms page images are stored

Comment: its save in pub/media/wysing folder, first verify the file save or not.

Comment: the file actually not saving...

Comment: pub/media/wysing   file permission is  777

Comment: i m sure, its only permission issue. when you upload files.

Comment: yes.....................
how i can solve this

Comment: when you upload file, check with inspect element file uploading or not, or you get 500 error etc.

Comment: when i insert image it's showing in media/wysing 

but the image file permission is 644 .
why??

Comment: which command are you using for file permission ?

Comment: i forgot that it's in server ...

Comment: any idea's  bro..........

Comment: please verify with server guy for permission.

Comment: i moved this backup to another server it's working fine and only not 
working on my old server
.
any idea's to fix this issue????

Comment: Yes I told you contact to your server guy, something wrong from server.